# keyboard column selection in Sublime Text 2 on Ubuntu 12.04 with Cinnamon doesn't work

Tags: sublimetext2, cinnamon

According to the [documentation](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/column_selection.html) for Linux column select uses the following commands:

Linux

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>

but on Ubuntu 12.04 with Cinnamon (not tested on Unity) this triggers the window switching operation (part of Cinnamon).

Anyone have a good fix for this (other than using the mouse...)

Thanks,

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Think that documentation is wrong. Just did a quick look into the `Default (Linux).sublime-keymaps` (which you can access from `Preferences` -> `Key Bindings - Default` but that's besides the point), and it looks to be alt+shift+(up/down). I was going to recommend rebinding the keys (thus the reason I was looking) but this may also solve your problem. =) Not tested, just based on the keymapping file. If that doesn't work, let me know.

Answer (score 31):

I am used to using `Ctrl+Alt+Up` and `Ctrl+Alt+Down` as shortcuts for this operation. To make it work in Linux, you have to do two steps. First, need to disable system wide shortcuts by typing:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down  "[]"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-up "[]"
```

Logout and login afterward. Source: https://gist.github.com/michfield/5614949

Second step is to edit the Sublime Text configuration file, and change accordingly. I assume that everybody know how to do that. Just in case, add this in `Preferences / Key Bindings - User`

```
// change column select defaults - on Linux it was Shift+Alt+Up/Down
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+up"], "command": "select_lines", "args": {"forward": false} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+down"], "command": "select_lines", "args": {"forward": true} }
```

Tested on Mint 15 Cinnamon (RC), based on Ubuntu Raring.

Comment: Works nicely, I'm just wondering which exactly did I disabled with those two commands?

Comment: Works for my Ubuntu 14.10 even without relogin. Thanks!

Comment: I used the System Settings window in Debian and didn't need to reboot, but still, basically did this. Thanks.

Comment: Two years and a half later this still works (Ubuntu 14.04). Thanks !

Comment: Worked for me in ubuntu with Gnome, Thanks !

Answer (score 11):

with mouse:

**Shift + Right Button** + (Drag up or down)

Comment: That's cool. If you don't have enough time to dig in system/sublime settings

Answer (score 10):

For me the problem  was different I normally use **Ctrl + Shift + up/down**

but then it stop working I really did not know why, my solution was to copy the default setting **from** Preferences-->Key Bindings - Default **to** Preferences-->Key Bindings - User

```
{ "keys": ["alt+shift+up"], "command": "select_lines", "args": {"forward": false} },
{ "keys": ["alt+shift+down"], "command": "select_lines", "args": {"forward": true} },
```

**Using sublime Text 3 Build 3083 in Ubuntu 14.04**

Comment: I've been searching for solution for a long time.worked for me

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know why, enter the Sublime 3 console:

```
cntl+`  # or View --> Show Console
```

Enter:

```
sublime.log_commands(True)
sublime.log_input(True)
```

Enter the naughty key combo and it'll show you the reason, typically a package installed will have a conflict. You can change it in that package key-bindings, or if you add new bindings to **User key-map** it'll override everything. (They are in  **Preferences-->Key Bindings**.)

EDIT: Using sublime Text 3 Build 3126 in Ubuntu 16.04